# Label control not filling its containing cell in TableLayoutPanel

Tags: c#, .net, tablelayoutpanel

What could cause a Label control to not grow/shrink to its containing cell inside of a TableLayoutPanel?  I have a few TableLayoutPanels inside another encompassing TableLayoutPanel.  I need the Label controls within the cells to adjust their size when the form is resized.  Button controls do this but Label controls do not.

I tried a simple experiment with Label controls in a more simpler example that uses just one TableLayoutPanel and it works; the Label controls resize fine when I set the Dock property to "fill," but I can't get it working in the form that has multiple TableLayoutPanel controls embedded within another one.

Microsoft suggests one should avoid nesting here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171689.aspx

However, I need to be able to make separate groups of controls within a TableLayoutPanel.  Can  anyone provide some insight?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you set the `Label.AutoSize` property of your labels to `false`? Per [MSDN's documentation on the `AutoSize` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171729(v=vs.110).aspx) (emphasis mine):

> The [Dock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.dock.aspx) and [Anchor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.anchor.aspx) properties are honored when [AutoSize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.autosize.aspx) is **true**.
>
> The value of the control's [Location](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.location.aspx) property is adjusted to the correct value.
> **Note** *The [Label](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.label.aspx) control is the exception to this rule. When you set the value of a docked [Label](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.label.aspx) control's [AutoSize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.autosize.aspx) property to **true**, the [Label](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.label.aspx) control will not stretch*.

Comment: My specific problem turned out to be somewhere else in the code was overriding that particular label's paint method, which forced it to be a fixed size.  Your answer is a good answer in general though so I will accept it.  Thanks!